# Print the variable name which is having same values

Tags: java

I'm trying to find greatest number and print the variable name which is having greatest number.There may be variables which is having same greatest number.I used if else logic to do this.

```
int a=2,b=2,c=1,great;
if((a>b)&&(a>c))
    great=a;
else if(b>c)
    great=b;
else
    great=c;
if(great==a)
    System.out.println("a");
else if(great==b)
    System.out.println("b");
else if((great==a)&&(great==b))
    System.out.println("a,b");
```

if suppose there 10 variables in that 9 variables having same values then print all the 9 variables name and it is complex to give all the conditions using if else. how can i do the same in simple logic?

Comment: The fundamental problem with your approach is using separate variables. This is better suited to an array of ints instead of a, b, c.... Have you learned about arrays yet?

Comment: You learn about arrays. And it would also help to learn about the space character. You can use that to add horizontal spacing to your code (called indentation) to make its hierarchical structure easier to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use separate variables...  (but using an array will be better, shorter, more easily extensible, able to copy with different numbers of inputs, etc).

Step 1 - figure out 'great'.

```
int great = a;
if (b > great) great = b;
if (c > great) great = c;
  :
```

Step 2 - print variable names; you only need mention each variable once.

```
if (a == great) System.out.print("a ");
if (b == great) System.out.print("b ");
if (c == great) System.out.print("c ");
  :
System.outprintln();
```

At no point do you have to deal with possible combinations; you can treat each variable by itself.  The code is repetitive, which an array would cure by permitting easy looping over the values.

I used space as a separator, rather than comma, since it's easier. No-one will notice a space after the last-printed name, whereas a comma would look wrong.

---

Fancier formatting.

```
// First we have to collect all "greatest" names.
// Always insert comma separator, which will leave us
// with (e.g.) ", a, b, c".  We'll fix it up later.
String names = "";
if (a == great) names += ", a";
if (b == great) names += ", b";
if (c == great) names += ", c";
  :

// If there are more than 2 greats we want to insert "and"
// thus ", a, b, c" => ", a, b, and c".  Note that another-dave
// is a fan of the oxford comma (so we do not want ", a, b and c").
if (names.length() > 6)  { // if more than 2 greats (3 chars each)
    names = names.substring(0, names.length()-1) + "and " +
            names.substring(names.length()-1);

// Finally, ditch the incorrect leading comma and space
names = names.substring(2);
```

Now you can print it, or whatever.

This is in my opinion pretty hacky but any improvement needs to use arrays.

Comment: Your logic is correct. But i need some modifications in output , if a and b are same then it prints "a,b is great" and if suppose a,b and c is same then it prints "a,b and c is great". How can i modify the code?

Comment: @Harini, just change >6 to >3 if you want to change "a, b is great" to "a and b is great".